# Adding inline stylesheets in HEAD on Next.js blog

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a blog (http://minid.net) in Jekyll that I want to migrate to Next.js. My blog doesn't use an external file for styles. I embedded all the styles in the HEAD element using a STYLE element. In Next.js, i created a Style.js component, that returns body {} but that throws an error.

[image]

```
export default function Styles() {
  return <style>body{background: red;}</style>;
}
```

My blog benefits from not having to use external files, each generated HTML has its styles, so I don't want to use the traditional global stylesheet for Next.js.

How can I solve this?

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: You seem to think that having external files is a bad thing. Having all your styles in a css file means that the browser will cache the file and your rendered html will be smaller.

Comment: If you have few styles, saving a hit from the server is faster than caching once.

Comment: I uploaded the error. I'm guessing if I should use dangeourslyinnerHTML for this.

Comment: Not sure if it works but can you try `return '<style>body{background: red;}</style>';`

Comment: @Kip that doesn't work.

Comment: Remember that it's a `jsx` that you're writing here, which is an extension of `javascript` and not `html`. Try using a backtick as part of string template literal.

Comment: Something like ``<style type="text/css">{`body {background-color: blue;}`}</style>``

Comment: @BumhanYu this worked flawlessly. I hope it works with the SSR too! thanks!

Comment: I personally use `styled-components` for `CSS-in-JS` styling, which seamlessly handles global styles and SSR as needed, and does help better organize all component-base styles without relying on external stylesheet. I'd suggest you use a tool like that to make your life easier.

Answer (score 4):

Take a read through this section of the docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#css-in-js

In summary you have to put the children of the `style` element inside of a string enclosed in brackets.

```
export default function Styles() {
  return (
    <style jsx>{`
      body{
        background: red;
      }
    `}</style>;
}
```

Comment: I don't know how you're using the styles but you might also need to add the global property to the style component

Comment: I found this info while reading the CSS implementation. This solution works but not for SSR https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/71

Answer (score 0):

you can use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

define the styles

```
const style = `<style>
body{color: blue; font-size: 18px;}
</style>`
```

and then put it anywhere in your page

```
<span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: style }} />
```